# How do I refer to my daughter's wife in context to our relationship? mother in law / not daughter in law

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms, sexual-minorities

My daughter is getting married this spring to a wonderful non-binary person. They will refer to me as their mother-in-law but I don’t want to be introducing them as "my daughter's wife".
What would be appropriate?

Comment: I don't know why you expect a single word for this when the traditional terms are things like "daughter-in-law" or "my daughter's wife". "My daughter's partner" would be logical, but obviously you should ask them not us.

Comment: As your own title says "I refer to my daughter's wife," *wife* and *daughter-in-law* are a good start until you hear a preference. Your own daughter could tell you.

Comment: Does the non-binary person even use the term *wife* to refer to themself?

Answer (score 3):

The gender neutral version of daughter-in-law (or son-in-law) is **child-in-law**. I haven't seen it used much personally, but it is used:

- > A person is a child-in-law to the parents of the spouse — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent-in-law)
- > Child-in-law means the spouse or domestic partner of a child. — [Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/child-in-law)
- > Spouses, Adult Children, and Children-in-Law as Caregivers of Older Adults: A Meta-Analytic Comparison — [paper title](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4449135/)

Alternatively, the gender neutral alternative to "daughter's wife" is "daughter's spouse" or "daughter's partner" which is a bit more common.

Comment: I believe **"child-in-law" is used as a placeholder for "son-in-law" and "daughter-in-law"** likewise **"children-in law"**. It is legal jargon used when the gender of the relative is irrelevant. Presumably the authors thought writing son/daughter-in-law(s)  would be unwieldy or just too long.  Nowhere do any of the cited sources mention that it can be used for non-binary relationships.

Comment: This isn't the first time I have come across the answer, I've been thinking about it and... "child" conjures a small young person who is not fully grown. Yes, I know you can be the child of a parent all your life, until you are in your seventies even, but I would quizzically raise an eyebrow if someone introduced me to their "child-in-law"!

Answer (score 3):

Ask them which they'd prefer & go with that.
They're probably aware you'll struggle to decide for yourself & you may opt for some 'least offensive' term in a tortuous middle-ground.

My niece & her married partner refer to themselves as wife & wife, Mrs & Mrs.   They don't look for some gender-neutral middle-ground. One took the surname of the other, 'traditional' style. They just got to chose which name, rather than have it decided for them.  Because it's uncle/nieces I don't have to look for a specific in-law version, they're both just 'nieces'.

Let them pick. That way everybody's happy. To disinterested third parties, you'll still have to say 'my daughter's wife', because if you say daughter-in-law, you'll then have to explain it. You can almost see the little cogs go round in people's heads until the idea drops into place. Most of the world is just about ready to fully accept the relationship these days, but it's never going to be their first guess if you say daughter-in-law.